# Angular2 cannot enter text into input field

Tags: windows, angular, internet-explorer

I am using Angular2 and when users go to my page using IE11 on Windows 7 (which appears to be the only combination that has issues) they cannot enter information into the textboxes/textareas.  The drop-downs work just fine as do the checkboxes (which will show/hide additional fields as needed although you still cannot enter information into the new text fields).

If the user clicks the submit button all the required fields show as needing input and then the user can enter the information.

If it matters, the users are redirected to this page after enter RECAPTCHA information.  If I take out the "canActivate" from my app routing module it works.

Here is the captcha code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
    Router,
    NavigationExtras
} from '@angular/router';
import { CaptchaService } from '../../utils/captchaguard/captcha.service';
import { ReCaptchaComponent } from 'angular2-recaptcha/lib/captcha.component';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'captcha.component.html'
})

export class CaptchaComponent {
    message: string;

    constructor(
        public captchaService: CaptchaService,
        public router: Router) {
        //this.captchaService.isLoggedIn = true;   //Uncomment out for testing
        this.captchaService.isLoggedIn = false;     //Uncomment out for live
    }

    handleCorrectCaptcha(userResponseKey: any) {
        let redirect = this.captchaService.redirectUrl ? this.captchaService.redirectUrl : '/admin';
        let redirectParts = redirect.split('/');
        let appendID = redirect[redirect.length - 1];
        //let appendID = 0;
        this.captchaService.isLoggedIn = true;
        //this.router.navigate(['/studyfd' + appendID]);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/studyfd' + appendID);
        //this.router.navigate(['/studytest/0']);
    }
}
```

Here is a portion of the HTML that generates the page in question:

```
<!-- First and Last Name -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        First Name, Last Name
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="firstname" required="required"
                                placeholder="First Name" class="required " 
                               [(ngModel)]="user.FirstName" *ngIf="!readonly" />
                        <label *ngIf="readonly">{{user.FirstName}}</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="text" name="LastName" id="lastName" required="required" 
                               placeholder="Last Name" [(ngModel)]="user.LastName" *ngIf="!readonly" 
                               class="required " />
                        <label *ngIf="readonly">{{user.LastName}}</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: What does the code look like?

Comment: please provide more source code information, so that we can help you

Comment: Entry updated with some of the code used.  Let me know if you think any other code would be useful.  The Captcha.service referenced is just used to store the redirectUrl variable.  Again I have tested with Windows 8, Windows 10, and Mac OS 10 as well as Chrome and Firefox on Windows7 and it is only Windows 7 with IE11 that has an issue.  Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was due to the RECAPTCHA window not closing (probably because of the redirect I was doing in handleCorrectCaptcha).  Resolved by adding a hidden button and in the handleCorrectCaptcha method I made the button visible.  Clicking on the button performed the redirect that was originally done in the handleCorrectCaptcha method.